# Display from my RX580 stays on for a few minutes at a time whenever PC is booted up, then goes dark

Tags: display, gpu, display-driver

For the past week it has been the case that my GPU simply does not output a display, although everything else works fine. Every few hours, if I restart the PC, the display comes on, though only for about 10 minutes, then goes blank again.

Whenever the display is on, I go to Device Manager which gives the error message "This device is not working properly because windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)".

Furthermore, if I try to open the AMD driver software (Adrenalin), I am given the error message "AMD software detected that the display driver has failed to load on your system".

In the short window of time that the display stays on, I have tried to "uninstall device" in Device Manager so that the drivers are deleted, then restart the PC to reinstall the GPU drivers. Doing this actually seems to work, with both Device Manager and AMD Adrenalin software showing no error messages, but the display still just goes blank after the 10 minutes. Then the next time I restart the PC and the display comes back on, the error messages return.

I'm hoping its just an issue with one of the settings in my BIOS or something, though the GPU is 2 years old, so I wouldn't rule out wear and tear. I would greatly appreciate any advice on the matter, and I'm willing to try out anything it takes to possibly solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming you are running Windows.

1. Boot into Safe Mode in Windows (10 and 11)

   1. From the sign in screen, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you select Power -> Restart
   2. The PC will restart to the **Choose an options** screen
   3. Select **Troubleshoot**
   4. Select **Advanced Options**
   5. Select **Startup Settings**
   6. Select **Restart**
2. Click on Task Bar
3. Type in *Device**
4. Select **Device Manager**
5. Select **Display Adapters** and expand it
6. Right click the driver and **Uninstall Device**

This will set the driver to a standard VGA.  Reboot normally and let windows update the driver.

**References **

[Start your PC in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)

[Can anything go wrong if I uninstall my display adapter in safe mode?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-anything-go-wrong-if-i-uninstall-my-display/844d8751-ce9e-4136-b0bf-6a4bae95e859)